# CSS button with button cropping the right side and background showing in the margin

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following button effect with css.

[image]

The html code for the buttons area is like this:

```
<div id="background">
<div id='button_region'>
  <div class="button">
     <a href="#">Services</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
     <a href="#">Support</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I asked chatGPT, and he suggested using clip-path, though, I still haven't been able to make it work.

How do code this css?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get that result you don't have to use clip-path you can achieve that result by using simple css too. here is code snippet. ask me if you don't understand anaything regarding this code.

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.button {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 40px;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  margin: 0 30px 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.button a::before {
  content: "<";
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
}
.button a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: -9px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3We.jpg?s=256&g=1");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id='button_region'>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Support</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is that your solution is using a white border around the circle. It will not work if the background is an image.

Comment: @justadev bro you can change color of that border to transparent and even use border-image property

Comment: I tried. But making the border transparent makes it show the button that is behind, not the background. The "inverse circle" solution is the right approach